# Typescript - Why does this recursive function skips some numbers?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

From the server, I receive this JSON object. It represents an organigram of a company and the associated departments.

I need to be able to choose a company, and with the ID of the company, I need to pass to an array of numbers the ID's of the associated departments.

For that, I've created this recursive function. It works, but, skips 3 departments, which are placed within another department

This is the JSON file

```
{
  "cd": 1,
  "cd_base": 0,
  "nome": "EMPRESA A",
  "children": [
    {
      "cd": 2,
      "cd_base": 1,
      "nome": "Departamento A",
      "children": [
        {
          "cd": 4,
          "cd_base": 2,
          "nome": "Serviço A1",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "cd": 15,
          "cd_base": 2,
          "nome": "Serviço A2",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cd": 3,
      "cd_base": 1,
      "nome": "Departamento B",
      "children": [
        {
          "cd": 7,
          "cd_base": 3,
          "nome": "Serviço B1",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cd": 186,
      "cd_base": 1,
      "nome": "Departamento XX",
      "children": []
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is the function in Typescript

```
recursiveFunction(res: any): any[] {
    const numbers = new Array(); // to store the ID
    console.log('Im on ' + res.cd + ' | ' + res.nome);
    numbers.push(res.cd);
    if (res.children.length > 0) {
      console.log(res.cd + ' | ' + res.nome + ' has children');
      res.children.forEach((row) => {
        numbers.push(row.cd);
        this.recursiveFunction(row);
      });
    } else {
      console.log(res.cd + ' | ' + res.nome + ' doesn\'t have any children');
    }
    return numbers;
  }
```

And this is the return of that function to the console

```
Im on 1 | EMPRESA A 
1 | EMPRESA A has c
Im on 2 | Departamento A 
2 | Departamento A has children 
Im on 4 | Serviço A1 
4 | Serviço A1 doesn't have any children 
Im on 15 | Serviço A2 
15 | Serviço A2 doesn't have any children 
Im on 3 | Departamento B 
3 | Departamento B has children 
Im on 7 | Serviço B1 
7 | Serviço B1 doesn't have any children 
Im on 186 | Departamento XX 
186 | Departamento XX doesn't have any children
```

Then I log the *numbers* array and the result is *1,2,3,186*

```
 this.numbers.forEach(row => {
    console.log(row);
  });
 // 1, 2, 3, 186
```

It adds the CD 1, 2, 3 and 186, but skips the 4, 7 and 15.
All of those are a branch/node **within** another branch/node

What am I missing? Is recursive the best way to do this? Is there a simpler way?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: 1. Your function is not recursive, because you call "recursiveCheckChildren" instead of "recursiveFunction". Please post the code of "recursiveCheckChildren()" so i can show you the issue.

Comment: Oh, I see, actually, it is, I've changed while writing the question --' 
Ill change the question. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Here is a solution for your problem with a recursive function: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cm2kqr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you've defined a recursive function that returns a result, but you're not using that result.

While the answer @aonepathan works, I would avoid using variables outside the scope of your function.

Instead all you have to do, is to concatenate the result of the function with the current array:

```
recursiveFunction(res: any): any[] {
let numbers = new Array(); // to store the ID
console.log('Im on ' + res.cd + ' | ' + res.nome);
numbers.push(res.cd);
if (res.children.length > 0) {
  console.log(res.cd + ' | ' + res.nome + ' has children');
  res.children.forEach((row) => {
    numbers = numbers.concat(this.recursiveFunction(row));
  });
} else {
  console.log(res.cd + ' | ' + res.nome + ' doesn\'t have any children');
}
return numbers;
}
```

Another option is to pass the numbers array around to your function calls, and so you get rid of the return:

```
recursiveFunction(res: any, numbers: any[]) {
console.log('Im on ' + res.cd + ' | ' + res.nome);
numbers.push(res.cd);
if (res.children.length > 0) {
  console.log(res.cd + ' | ' + res.nome + ' has children');
  res.children.forEach((row) => {
    this.recursiveFunction(row, numbers);
  });
} else {
  console.log(res.cd + ' | ' + res.nome + ' doesn\'t have any children');
}
}
```

The first time you'd call this, would be with a new Array:

```
let result = new Array();
recursiveFunction(res, result);
doSomething(result);
```

Comment: Many thanks!
As you stated, I rather also not to use variables outside of the scope, so I'll go for this one

Comment: agreed, the variable scoping and this answer is more appropriate!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you might have been re-initializing the numbers array every time the function gets called again, consider moving it outside of the function:

```
const numbers = new Array();

function recursiveFunction(res: any): any[] {
    console.log('Im on ' + res.cd + ' | ' + res.nome);
  numbers.push(res.cd);
    if (res.children.length > 0) {
      console.log(res.cd + ' | ' + res.nome + ' has children');
      res.children.forEach((row) => {
        // numbers.push(row.cd);
        this.recursiveFunction(row);
      });
    } else {
      console.log(res.cd + ' | ' + res.nome + ' doesn\'t have any children');
  }
    return numbers;
}
```

I got rid of the second push as once you recall the function the ID gets pushed into the numbers array.

Console: 1, 2, 4, 15, 3, 7, 186

Comment: I fell kinda dumb :)
But thanks. This is exactly what I needed :)